# Java check for valid string format

Tags: java, regex

Hi guys I need to check whether a string is in valid format or not.

**Sample strings:**

```
John 3:16 = true
Luke 1:1 = true
Marth232:f = false
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\s]|:");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("John12:3");
boolean  b = m.find();

System.out.println("Boolean: " + b);
```

But it's getting True instead of False. Any ideas? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: [`[a-zA-Z]+ \d+:\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/iP2uQ0/1)

Comment: Why you added space and , inside the char clas?

Comment: @Tushar I'm getting illegal escape character

Comment: @AvinashRaj sorry I mistyped it

Comment: You might need to add extra slash before `\d`

Comment: you also forget the anchors..

Comment: @Tushar wow it works! Thanks

Comment: @bEtTy Barnes: since this is java you have to escape the backslashes using backslashes: `"[a-zA-Z]+ \\d+:\\d+"`. And don't talk about regexps looking for double backslashes.....

Comment: @piet.t thanks for explaining dude!

Comment: alternative syntax : `\\p{Alpha}+ \\d+:\\d+`